# Установка Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Добрый вечер.Поступил ноутбук с проблемой,когда заходишь на любого пользователя сразу же выкидывает обратно,с дисков установочных windows не запускается(диски проверяли работают везде), взял как обычно загрузочную флешку,начал ставить, но в ходе установки(грузиться отладчик ядра dll не помню точно) компьютер выключается так и не дойдя до выбора меню. Прошу помощи что это может быть и как решить проблему,спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь запишите какой нибудь Hiren boot CD на флешку и проверьте железо например озу и проц,если все в порядке сбросьте биос. результат отпишите я пока подумаю что еще можно сделать

Comment: bios обнулил не чего не помогло,я сейчас не дома,с инетом проблема,он есть но медленный буду скоро дома через день два буду пробовать Hiren boot CD,спасибо за отзыв.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что за программа указана в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` . Проверьте не заражен ли explorer.exe.Можете загрузиться с [AntiWinLocker liveCD](http://www.antiwinlocker.ru/download.html).

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать ,если что обязательно отпишу.

Comment: И что?.. Получилось что-нибудь?